# Latex error with enumitem.sty

Tags: fonts, enumitem

In currently installed MacTex full version but when I run a tex file I get the following error, any help woul be appreciated

```
! LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found.
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you add a full code or the .log file for your errors? My best regards.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have two LaTeX installations installed? Expecially the MacPort one?

Comment: You could post the log file

Comment: the lof file is empty, I installed maxtex and then xelatex, maybe thats causing the problem...

Comment: That does not make sense. If even enumitem cannot be found, there should still be a log file. MacTeX already include xelatex, so please please exaplain exactly what you have done?

Comment: BTW: use @username to ping the person you are adressing with your comment

Comment: Could have been a typo or could be relevant: The relevant LaTeX log that daleif asked for is in the `.log` file (with **`g`**). The `.lof` file (with **`f`**) may containn information for the list of figures and is not directly relevant here.

Comment: Could you please let us have a minimal example file that shows your problem? what do you mean by " I installed maxtex and then xelatex" since xe(la)tex is already a part of the TeX Live distribution installed by MacTeX?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I installed xe(la)tex separetely due to a font problem, and that messed up the Tex Live installation, after a clean install everything is working again.